# Как дать понять что все элементы страницы загрузились?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Есть страничка которая загружается и полностью рендерится за 1 секунду. В это время у меня идёт запрос к базе в получение JSON данных, которые кладутся в `scope` ангуляра таким методом:

```
$http.get(path)
     .then(function (response) {
         $scope.currentProduct = response.data[0];
         $scope.allProducts = response.data.slice(1, response.data.length);
     });
```

Они подгружаются чуть чуть позже (допустим через 1 сек после того как загрузилась остальная страничка).

В этот момент страница уже полностью отрисована, только места где должны выводиться данные пока пустые. Код который выводит наши продукты:

```
<div class="col col-md-12">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li class="upcoming-item" ng-repeat="item in allProducts">
            <div class="panel panel-default">                                                         
                    <small ng-bind="item.Name"></small>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Мне нужно чтобы вывелись все продукты в список `<li>`, а потом я по эттому списку буду вызывать метод который создаст из списка красивый слайдер.

Проблема в том что у меня идёт такой порядок: страничка без ангуляра, инициализация слайдера (он видит что пусто и ничего не строит) и заполнение страницы ангуляровскими данными

Как мне отловить момент когда ВСЁ загрузилось на страницу. Методы типа window.load срабатывают когда рендерится страница, раньше того как приходят и отрисовываются данные с базы

Comment: лучше бы добавил пример в предыдущий вопрос, чем задавать новый.

Comment: предыдущий вопрос был некорректно задан, поэтому я его удалил и задал новый. Примеры сейчас сюда прикреплю

Comment: Отследить загрузку страницы можно через метод load(), ссылка на статью: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ 
и повесь метод setTimeout()
https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/
 для того, чтобы твоё условие выполнилось через определенное время

Comment: неподходящий способ. Данные получаются с различной скоростью в зависимости от интернет соединения. При скорости интернета 450 кб\с -11 секунд. Не буду же я ставить 11с задержку

Comment: @DenisLazarev, здесь используется angular - jquery - Тут не поможет

Comment: если под _загрузилось на страницу_ ты имеешь ввиду отрисовалось - то никак.

Comment: да именно это и имею ввиду

Comment: возможно тебе может помочь этот вопрос: [Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15207788/2881286)

Comment: Ответ в вашем вопросе: отловите завершение заполнения страницы данными angular. Скорее всего в документации есть функция.

Answer (score -1):

Читай описание функции тут https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.get/

Третий параметр задает функцию, которая будет выполняться в случае успеха.

Так же почитай тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re (вроде как лучший ответ по твоей теме?)

Comment: _вроде как лучший ответ по твоей теме?_ - на самом деле один из худших, начиная с того, что синхронные запросы потихоньку запрещаются браузерами, и заканчивая тем, что проблема не в получении данных, а в отслеживании момента, когда по этим данным **ангуляром** будет добавлена разметка

Comment: вообще не то что надо.. Мне не нужно отлавливать момент успеха получения данных. Мне нужно отловить момент заполнения страницы данными ангуляора

Comment: А реально может потребоваться много времени после получения всех данных? Как вариант: ставим в данных маячок, ставим SetTimeout и проверяем появление маячка на странице.

Comment: про ангулар есть похожий вопрос тут https://javascript.ru/forum/angular/40561-vyzov-funkcii-kontrollera-posle-zagruzki-stranicy.html